# Angular: Cannot display the array of objects received from the Http Respnse in the HTML page of Component

Tags: angular, templates, ngfor

The component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { error } from 'selenium-webdriver';
import { HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http/src/response';
interface Todo {
  result: string[];
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})

export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  results: String[];
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get<Todo>('http://localhost:3000/todos').subscribe(data => { 
      this.results = data.result;
      console.log(data);
    },    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      if (err.error instanceof Error) {
        // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
        console.log('An error occurred:', err.error.message);
      } else {
        // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
        // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
        console.log(`Backend returned code ${err.status}, body was: ${err.error}`);
      }
    }
    );
  }

}
```

The component.html file

```
<div>Works</div>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let result of results">{{result.text}}</li>
</ul>
```

I get a HTTP 304 Status code and the returned data is an array of Objects. 
The json data returned by the Http response:

```
0: Object { _id: "5a53460339ff2c2488a7bee1", text: "Invade the north tower", __v: 0, … }
1: Object { _id: "5a53464539ff2c2488a7bee2", text: "Collect invisibility rune from Dunaki", __v: 0, … }
2: Object { _id: "5a53465b39ff2c2488a7bee3", text: "Meet Shinoko", __v: 0, … }
3: Object { _id: "5a53585a62ce2331a889556e", text: "xyz", __v: 0, … }
4: Object { _id: "5a5450ce486ddb1e184567ae", __v: 0, date: "2018-01-09T05:19:10.713Z" }
```

The data is retrieved and stored in the component's `results` array, but it is not displayed in the html.
While observing the console, I noticed that the html was rendered first and the response was received after that. But I have mentioned the retrieval logic in the ngOnInit(). 
Please guide me, thank you!

Comment: have errors in console ?

Comment: The console prints the above array. Anyways, I was wrong to use `this.results = data.result`, since the data had no `result` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't this line:

```
this.results = data.result;
```

Be just this:

```
this.results = data;
```

You are showing just `data` in the console.log and I don't see that it has a `result` property?

UPDATE from comments below:
This is the code from the example linked in the comments to this post:

```
http.get<ItemsResponse>('/api/items').subscribe(data => {
  // data is now an instance of type ItemsResponse, so you can do this:
  this.results = data.results;
});
```

Comment: Maybe , items are contained in data.result

Comment: Not if the console.log displayed the above-shown output. Or maybe the "json data returned" shown above wasn't from that console.log?

Comment: I followed this guide [angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/http), where it says that the data which we get from the request is instance of Todo interface.

Comment: `data.result` is an array of Objects

Comment: If you are following that example exactly, then it is `data.results` (plural), not `data.result`, singular. I updated my answer with a relevant snippet from that link.

Comment: sorry `data.result` is `undefined`,Thank you @DeborahK

Comment: `data.result` is undefined while just `data` is an array of objects. And now to store the value from `data` to `this.results` I will have change its type to `any` which is not what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

You must fill list in ngAfterViewInit() method. That's why ngOnInit works first. And after HTML has been loaded, ngAfterViewInit works.

Comment: The data binding will cause the display to update whenever the data is retrieved. No need to move it to AfterViewInit.

Comment: Oh, it's true but i couldn't solve it this way. AfterViewInit had worked for me :)

Comment: I'd be interested to see a data retrieval issue solved by moving the code to the AfterViewInit. Could you post some sample code?

Comment: I can say that, I fill lists used in HTML, in function connected to AfterViewInit(). And may not be a right use, i'm new about Angular :)